# Android spinner dropdown icon get hidden under background image

Tags: android, xamarin.android, dropdown, android-spinner

I am using `Spinner` in my android application where I use `Spinner` in a `LinearLayout` and  I use `Relative Layout` with image background and `LinerLayout` inside `FrameLayout` to show the background image. In this case, my dropdown icon getting hidden behind the background image. Here my sample code.

```
<FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#FFFF"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/mainLinearLayout">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:background="@drawable/devbg"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"> 
      <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/dropStatus"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.DropDownItem.Spinner"
            android:theme="@style/CardView.Dark"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:foregroundTint="#FF000000"
            android:backgroundTint="#FF000000"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/> 
   </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know why you use `RelativeLayout` to set the background. Delete it and set the background in `LinearLayout`, everything would be okay.

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFF"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainLinearLayout">
<LinearLayout
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:background="@drawable/pink"> 
  <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/dropStatus"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.DropDownItem.Spinner"
        android:theme="@style/CardView.Dark"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:foregroundTint="#FF000000"
        android:backgroundTint="#FF000000"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/> 
 </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

can you try this code?

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#FFFF"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/mainLinearLayout">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:src="@drawable/devbg"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/dropStatus"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.DropDownItem.Spinner"
        android:theme="@style/CardView.Dark"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:foregroundTint="#FF000000"
        android:backgroundTint="#FF000000"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I have white background image and the icon color is black as I set in background tint color in spinner , so the icon is shown as black in preview. But not in device. WHen I remove the image it shows in device.

Comment: Tried but the dropdown icon is not appearing. It shows only when I remove the background image.